# Filter by count of items in Tortoise ManyToManyField

Tags: python, database, orm, tortoise-orm

I'm trying to make a `trending` command for my application which gets the recent posts and displays them ranked by amount of likes and comments. Each `Post` model has a `likes` and `comments` field.

```py
likes: fields.ManyToManyRelation["User"] = fields.ManyToManyField(
    "connect.User", related_name="liked", through="like_user"
)
```

```py
comments: fields.ReverseRelation["Comment"]
```

The problem I'm having is now I can't find a way to filter by *amount* of likes and comments, as you can't filter by ManyToMany fields or ReverseRelations.

```py
posts = Post.filter(
    likes__gt=0,
    comments__gt=0,
    created_at__gt=datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days=7),
    filter__lte=user.config.filter,
)
```

This doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For number of likes that has many to many relationship would be something like this:

```
posts_ids = (
    await Post.annotate(num_likes=Count('likes'))
    .filter(num_likes__gt=0,
            created_at__gt=datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days=7),
            filter__lte=user.config.filter,
    )
    .group_by('id')
    .order_by('-num_likes')
    .values_list('id', 'num_likes')
)
```